# MFC personalized menu behaviour

Tags: mfc

I generated a MDI tabbed CView project using App. wizard using Personalized menu behavior.
How can i disable personalized menu behaviour ( i dont want it), because i want to see the whole menu at once when i click it. Do i have to generate the project all over again or can i change something in the code to disable it ?

Comment: Do you want to disable it or hide it?

Answer (score 2):

In your `CMainFrame::OnCreate` method, find the comment that says `// enable menu personalization`.

Following this will be a couple dozen lines of code that builds a `CList` of commands, and then calls `CMFCToolbar::SetBasicCommands()`.

Remove the `CList` and the `AddTail` calls that build the list. And remove the call to `SetBasicCommands`. Your menu will now be a “normal” non-personalized menu.

Comment: Thanks Nate, i just did not see the 'enable menu personalization' comment the first time i checked the code before i asked the question. I removed the code and now it shows the menus as i want it.